# if statement only recognizing certain integers in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter value: ");
    int value = input.nextInt();

    if (value == 1 || value == 3 || value == 5 ||value == 7 || value == 9) {
        if (value % 3 == 0)
            System.out.println(value + " is an odd number less than 10"
                    + " and divisible by 3");
    }
    else if (value == 2 || value == 4 || value == 6 ||value == 8) {
        if (value % 3 == 0)
            System.out.println(value + " is an even number less than 10"
                    + " and divisible by 3");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid number");
    input.close();
}
```

if-else statement only recognizes integers that are divisible by 3 which are **3**, **6 or 9**. When I type 1 or 5, for example, the programme does not display any of the input and just stop running.

Comment: you are not printing anything if the number is not divisible by 3...

Comment: Based on my testing `value % 3` doesn't  `== 0`

Comment: If `value == 2`, then how could it *possibly* be divisible by 3? You have a lot of unnecessary checks here.

Answer (score 1):

If you type "1" then `if(value == 1)` is `true` so then the program checks `if(value %3 == 0)`. Since `value%3` is `1` when value is 1 it doesn't print anything and exits. So you see nothing.

Normally, in any IDE there are some debugging facilities so by using them you will be able to see how the program works step by step.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you used this particular logic in your `if` statements, but we can refactor assuming what you print is actually what you want:

> is an odd/even number less than 10 and divisble by 3

```
if (value < 10 && value % 2 == 1 && value % 3 == 0) {
    System.out.println(value + " is an odd number less than 10"
                + " and divisible by 3");
}
else if (value < 10 && value % 2 == 0 && value % 3 == 0) {
    System.out.println(value + " is an even number less than 10"
                + " and divisible by 3");
}
else {
    System.out.println("value does not meet our conditions.");
}
```

The immediate reason why 1 and 5 apparently cause the code to do nothing is that they enter the first `if` statement but then fail the next condition as they are not divisible by three, and your code does not output in this case.

Comment: Yes, I wanted something like this. Thank you so much! I'm still finding my way around Java.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the given logic. When you type 1 or 5 as input first outer if becomes true. But `if(value % 3 == 0)` isn't true, that's why program ended up without giving any output. 
If I understand your expectation of this program correctly please try the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter value: ");
int value = input.nextInt();

if (value < 10 && value % 2 == 0 && value % 3 == 0) {
    System.out.println(value + " is an even number less than 10" + " and divisible by 3");

}
else if (value < 10 && value % 2 != 0 && value % 3 == 0) {
    System.out.println(value + " is an odd number less than 10" + " and divisible by 3");

}
else
    System.out.println("Invalid number");
input.close();
```

}

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thanks! I'm still finding my way around Java.

Answer (score 0):

when you enter 1 or 5 for example, below condition becomes true

if (value == 1 || value == 3 || value == 5 ||value == 7 || value == 9)

however, value %3 is not equal to 0 hence nothing is printed and program control directly goes to

input.close();

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not use if-else statements that way. Now, the problem is that when you enter 1 or 5, they pass the first if statement, but neither (1 % 3 ==0) or (5 % 3 == 0) will be true, and that is why your code does nothing in those cases. Try this instead:

```
if(value % 3 == 0 && value <10) {
    if(value % 2 != 0){
        System.out.println(value + " is an odd number less than 10"
                + " and divisible by 3"); 
    }else{
       System.out.println(value + " is an even number less than 10"
                + " and divisible by 3");
    }
}else{
    System.out.println("Invalid number");
}
```